# fetch inner json object using javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I am new to node and I am trying to fetch name from the obj but the problem is

How to fetch data from inner json object as my json object look like this

```js
let obj= 
{
  "h4354desdfqw":{
   name:"Computer",
   os:"Window",
  },
  "hjsado24334":{
   name:"Software",
   type:"Adobe",
  },
  "qwsak032142":{
   name:"hardware",
   type:"hardisk",
  },
}

console.log(obj.h4354desdfqw.name)
```

I am trying to fetch all the name which are present inside the json object
like this

```
computer
Software
hardware
```

Comment: `Object.values(obj)` and `map` will help

Comment: There's no [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) in your question: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation), and [there's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure in which representation you would like get the data. I can assume - you would like to get array of the names

```js
let obj= 
{
  "h4354desdfqw":{
   name:"Computer",
   os:"Window",
  },
  "hjsado24334":{
   name:"Software",
   type:"Adobe",
  },
  "qwsak032142":{
   name:"hardware",
   type:"hardisk",
  },
}

const result = Object.values(obj).map(i => i.name);

console.log(result)

Object.values(obj).map(i => console.log(i.name));
```

Comment: can I get output without square bracket? @shutsman

Comment: yes, we can, but these strings should be stored somewhere and array is the best way, we can simply log on each iteration

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the value of `name` for each object.
So let's iterate through each object's name with the map function :

```
const result = Object.values(obj).map(i => i.name);
console.log(result);
```